# Opening new window with google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

What I'm doing is creating a google app script to calculate a value with the form data and then open a new window to display that number to the user. I am currently using this code but I keep on receiving the error that window is not found.

```
var myWindow=window.open("", "Results", "width=200, height=100"); 
myWindow.document.write("<p>Your score is "+score+" </p>");
```

Any suggestions/workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using HtmlService in Google Apps Script. Have you checked the restriction which HtmlService imposes on certain browser objects?

> Your JavaScript does not have full access to the surrounding browser.
>   You cannot, for example, read cookies, navigate the history, or set
>   the title of the window

Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#browser_access